# An inequality related to matrix norms and the trace distance of two matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose that $U_1,U_2$ are unitary matrices. A paper [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0508139) (page 4) I am reading gives the following set of inequalities (using Dirac notation here for vectors representing pure quantum states, aka. tensor products of vectors in $\mathbb{C}^2$ with length $1$).

$$
\|U_1 - U_2\| \geq \|U_1 |\psi \rangle - U_2 |\psi \rangle\| \geq \frac {1}{2}\operatorname{Trace}\left |U_1 |\psi \rangle \langle \psi| U_1^{\dagger} - U_2 |\psi \rangle \langle \psi| U_2^{\dagger}\right| \\
= D (U_1 |\psi \rangle \langle \psi| U_1^{\dagger} - U_2 |\psi \rangle \langle \psi| U_2^{\dagger}),$$

where $D$ is the trace distance.

The norm used is not stated. Here are some things I know related to these inequalities:

1) Unitary matrices preserve the length of vectors

2) If $|| A||$ is a matrix norm induced by a vector norm, then for $||x||=1$, $||A|| \geq ||Ax||$, which would explain the first inequality. I'm not sure what is happening in the second inequality. Insights appreciated.

Comment: I've edited your question to make it clearer, is the current version accurate?

Comment: Also, do you have a link to the paper?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom yes it is. I will link it.

Comment: I think that the norm is indeed the induced vector norm, as you've stated.  I think that the inequality being used in the second step is 
$$
\|x - y\| \geq \frac 12 \operatorname{Trace}|xx^* - yy^*|
$$
for vectors $x,y \in \Bbb C^n$.  I don't immediately see why this would hold, though.

Comment: The trace in question would be $\sum |x_i^2 - y_i^2|$. 
Supposing that the norm we used was euclidian, i.e. $||x-y||^2 = \sum |x_i - y_i|^2$, we can say that $|x_i^2-y_i^2|  \leq |x_i-y_i|( |x_i+y_i|)$. Next we use Cauchy Schwarz and the triangle inequality for $||.||_2$ norm to get the result. I've used the fact that the 2 norm of these vectors is 1, which is maybe bold haha

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst if you post your comment as an answer then I will study it and accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chain of inequalities makes sense if we add in the following.

> **Claim:** For any unit vectors $x,y$, we have 
>   $$
> \|x - y\| \geq \frac 12 \operatorname{Tr}|xx^* - yy^*|.
> $$

**Proof:** Noting that $x$ and $y$ are unit vectors, we compute
$$
\|x - y\|^2 = (x-y)^*(x-y) =  x^*x - x^*y - y^*x + y^*y \\
= 1 - \langle x, y\rangle - \langle y,x \rangle + 1 = 2(1 - \operatorname{Re}\langle x,y \rangle)
$$
So, we have $\|x - y\| = \sqrt{2}\sqrt{1 - \operatorname{Re}\langle x,y \rangle}$.

On the other hand, $A = (xx^* - yy^*)$ is a rank-2 Hermitian matrix with trace zero, which means that it has non-zero eigenvalues $\pm \lambda$ for some $\lambda>0$.  We compute
$$
\begin{align*}
    2\lambda^2 &= \lambda^2 + (-\lambda)^2 = \operatorname{Tr}(A^2) = \operatorname{Tr}[(xx^* - yy^*)^2] 
\\ & = \operatorname{Tr}[xx^*xx^* - xx^*yy^* - yy^*xx^* + yy^*yy^*]
    \\ & = 
    \operatorname{Tr}[x^*xx^*x - x^*yy^*x - y^*xx^*y + y^*yy^*y] 
\\ &= 
    \langle x,x\rangle^2 - 2|\langle x,y\rangle|^2 + \langle y,y \rangle^2
    \\ & = 
    2 - 2|\langle x,y\rangle|^2
\end{align*}
$$
We thereby conclude that $\lambda = \sqrt{1 - |\langle x,y \rangle|}$.  Thus, we compute
$$
\frac 12 \operatorname{Tr}|xx^* - yy^*| = \frac 12 (2 \lambda) = \sqrt{1 - |\langle x,y \rangle|}.
$$

Thus, it suffices to show that 
$$
\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1 - \operatorname{Re}\langle x,y \rangle} \geq 
\sqrt{1 - |\langle x,y \rangle|}.
$$
Indeed, we have
$$
\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1 - \operatorname{Re}\langle x,y \rangle} \geq 
\sqrt{1 - |\langle x,y \rangle|} \iff\\
2(1 - \operatorname{Re}\langle x,y \rangle) \geq 1 - |\langle x, y \rangle| \iff \\
1 + |\langle x, y \rangle| \geq 2 \operatorname{Re}\langle x,y \rangle \iff\\
\frac{1 + |\langle x, y \rangle|}{2} \geq \operatorname{Re}\langle x,y \rangle.
$$
The last inequality can be shown to hold as follows: by Cauchy Schwarz, $|\langle x, y \rangle| < 1$.  So, 
$$
\frac{1 + |\langle x, y \rangle|}{2} \geq |\langle x,y \rangle| = \sqrt{(\operatorname{Re}\langle x,y \rangle)^2 + (\operatorname{Im} \langle x,y\rangle)^2} \\
\qquad \qquad \quad\geq
\sqrt{(\operatorname{Re}\langle x,y \rangle)^2} = |\operatorname{Re}\langle x,y \rangle| \geq \operatorname{Re}\langle x,y \rangle.
$$

Comment: Why does $A$ have rank $2$, and why is it's trace $0$? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for the rushed answer.  Assuming that $x \neq y$ so that $A \neq 0$, $A$ has trace $0$ since
$$
\operatorname{Tr}(A) = \operatorname{Tr}(xx^* - yy^*) = x^*x - y^*y = 1 - 1 = 0
$$
As for the rank: $A$ is the sum of $2$ rank-1 operators, so its rank is at most $2$.  Since $A$ is a non-zero matrix with rank at most 2 and trace zero, it must have eigenvalues $\pm \lambda$ (and therefore rank exactly $2$).

Comment: Note that for a Hermitian matrix, the rank of $A$ is the total number of non-zero eigenvalues of $A$.

Comment: If you want a reference for the inequalities, I think that this is one of the Fuchs van der Graaf inequalities.  Watrous's text "theory of quantum information" should have this in there somewhere.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help, I need to study it all before I can say much more but this is exactly what I was looking for.